# Why use response.json() on both server and client side to access json object

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, express, mean-stack

I am new to MEAN stack, 
here is my API, I have used **res.json(random)** to send a random password

```
module.exports.changePass = function (req, res) {
    console.log(req.body.email)

db.user.find({ where: { name: req.body.name, email: req.body.email } }
    ).then(function (result) {
        if (result == null) {
            res.statusCode = '400'
            res.json({
                'error': 'Bad request, user not found'
            })
        } else {
            var random = Math.random().toString(36).slice(-8);
            result.updateAttributes({
                password: random
            }).then(function (result) {
                res.statusCode = '200';
                res.json(
                    random
                );
            });
        }
    });
}
```

Here is the client side code (Angular), I have used **response.json()** so that I can access that random password

```
    this.http.post('http://localhost:3000/fp',
 { name: this.name, email: this.email })
.toPromise().then((response) => {
            alert('fp successful. ' + response.json());
          }).catch((error: any) => {
            if (error.status === 400) {
              alert("User not found");
              return Observable.throw(new Error(error.status));
            }
          });
```

My question is that , when i am sending response from server as json then why we have to convert that response again to json at client side , to access that object ?

Comment: because you're alerting it. alerts use strings. alerting an object isn't useful.

Comment: because it is a string, you are not passing an object.

Answer (score 0):

JSON is a text-based format. The response.json function call likely converts the JavaScript object into the string and sets the correct mime-type. Depending on what library you are using on the client side, can parse it automatically (like jQuery) or not in your case.

Comment: my question got a down vote, your answer got a down vote, :/

Comment: @DaniyalJavaid oh well. i hope my answer helps you.